Ask cmake to use an old version of C++ to compile program
I am trying to compile a program (ANA, following these instructions) on my MacBook Pro M1 Max (macOS 14.5), but the installation consistently fails. The final lines from the compilation log are:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.5.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:1037:41: note: expanded from macro '_LIBCPP_DEPRECATED_IN_CXX17'
#    define _LIBCPP_DEPRECATED_IN_CXX17 _LIBCPP_DEPRECATED
                                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.5.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__config:1010:49: note: expanded from macro '_LIBCPP_DEPRECATED'
#      define _LIBCPP_DEPRECATED __attribute__((__deprecated__))
                                                ^
3 warnings generated.
5 warnings generated.
[100%] Linking CXX executable ANA2
ld: library 'gmp' not found
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [ANA2] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ANA2.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Looking through the error messages, one repeated message I am noticing goes along the lines of:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX14.5.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__memory/allocator.h:155:61: note: 'allocate' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
_LIBCPP_NODISCARD_AFTER_CXX17 _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_DEPRECATED_IN_CXX17

I am by no means an expert at compiling programs (I much prefer MacPorts to do the job for me), but my interpretation of this error message is that a command (allocate) was deprecated in version 17 of C++.
In order to make progress, my thought was to try and tell the compiler to use an old version of C++ to compile the program. I am using the default compiler on my computer (Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)), and I had assumed that I would need to invoke the -std=c++14 option, but it does not seem to work for the cmake or make commands.
I have two questions:

Is the compilation issue related to the C++ version I am using?
How can I tell make/cmake to use a specific version of C++ to compile the code? Is it even possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
P.S. I have made sure that gmp is installed and located in my path; I think I will have to deal with that problem another day.

SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14) ?

Please post the beginning of the error, not the last lines.

The only fatal error in what you show is ld: library 'gmp' not found.

@HolyBlackCat there is not one single error—it goes through an entire compilation routine (outlining each step in the log), but ends with the lines I posted. What should I search for in the log file that will show me the source of the error?

@ChrisMM where would I set that? In the Makefile?

Start from the first occurrence of error.

@HolyBlackCat It looks like there are only two occurrences of the word 'error', and the other occurrence is not an error message, but a notification that a file called derror.c.o has been built...

Ah nevermind, Mat was right. I thought those note:s belonged to another error, but probably that was just a warning.

@HolyBlackCat Fair enough. I'm starting to get that feeling myself, too... Apparently the gmp library is no longer being maintained by ING, so I suspect there may be no way to install this program, unfortunately...
